# Servlet and html form for calculator

Tags: html, eclipse, servlets

I want to make calculator which basically add, subtract, multiply and divide two numbers. For achieving this first of all i have designed a form in HTML and feel desire to calculate the answer on server so i have written a code on servlet but when i hit the submit button of my form it will do nothing. 
Note: i am working eclipse so you are requested to answer my question with respect to eclipse.
Calculator.java:

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Calculator extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        try
        {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
        int a1= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n1"));
        int a2= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n2"));
        if(request.getParameter("r1")!=null)
        {
            out.println("<h1>Addition</h1>"+(a1+a2));
        }
        if(request.getParameter("r2")!=null)
        {
            out.println("<h1>Substraction</h1>"+(a1-a2));
        }
        if(request.getParameter("r3")!=null)
        {
            out.println("<h1>Multiplication</h1>"+(a1*a2));
        }if(request.getParameter("r1")!=null)
        {
            out.println("<h1>Division</h1>"+(a1/a2));
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text_align=center">Calculator</h1>
<form method="get" action="/Servlet">
<label>first number:</label>
<input type="text" name="n1" />
<br />
<label>Second number : </label>
<input type="text" name="n2" />
<br />
 <div>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="add" />addition
<br />
</label>
<input type="radio" name="r2" value="sub" />subtraction 
<br />
<input type="radio" name="r3" value="mul" />multiplication
<br />
<input type="radio" name="r4" value="div" />division
<br /> 
</div>
<input type="button" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.Calculator</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/firstHomePage</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: May be there are some errors.
Try Writing e.printStackTrace(): inside catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written url-pattern 'firstHomePage' in web.xml for servlet name Calculator

```
        <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/firstHomePage</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>
```

so that what you should write in form action i.e.

```
      <form action="firstHomePage" method="get">
```

(you don't write / in form action)

whatever you write inside form action is checked in the url-pattern of all servlets mappings when a match is found the respective servlet name and the corresponding servlet class is searched for. That's how it works.

Hope you got your answer :)

UPDATE: write

```
      <input type="submit">
```

**NOT BUTTON** else your form won't submit.
If you are using  `button`  then you will have to write some javascript.

Comment: no i am just thinking HTML submit button in not able to instantiate the servlet and action attribute is being given a wrong url value..

Comment: I am very grateful for help.. At last it is working..I am sorry for committing this type of silly mistake..