# Calculator with servlets?

Tags: html, servlets, calculator

I want to make a html calculator like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078140/servlet-and-html-form-for-calculator).
He made his calculator so that when you calculate the result, a new html page will be loaded and only the results will be shown. 
I want to make the same calculator but I don't want to load a new page when the results are calculated, in fact, I want to display it in a textfield on the same page where you entered the two numbers.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can either use AJAX, or have the result calculated on the servlet page and redirect back to the page with the input-form, and display the content returned from the servlet. A simple calculation should be more or less instant, so the user shouldn't really notice either way.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but how do I redirect to the page with the input form? Every time I refresh the page, my input resets.

Comment: What tech are you using? "Servlets" can be a lot of things...